# Oracle foreign key allow one extra specific value

Tags: oracle, constraints

I have one simple table:

```
-- Create table
create table FAVOURITE_RULES
( rule_id NUMBER(9) not null,
  user_id     NUMBER(9) not null);
-- Create/Recreate primary, unique and foreign key constraints 
alter table FAVOURITE_RULES
 add constraint FAV_RULES_PK primary key (RULE_ID, USER_ID)

alter table FAVOURITE_RULES
 add constraint FAV_RULES_RULE_ID_FK foreign key (RULE_ID)
 references RULES (RULE_ID) on delete cascade;

alter table FAVOURITE_RULES
 add constraint FAV_RULES_USER_ID foreign key (USER_ID)
 references USER_AUTHENTICATION (USER_ID) on delete cascade;
```

I have a rule (from .Net code) that doesn't exist in the original table RULES. It has the Id=-999.
When I try to insert into the FAVOURITE_RULES I get an error about integrity constraint violation (as expected) (FAV_RULES_RULE_ID_FK) violated - parent key not found.
Can I keep the foreign key (FAV_RULES_RULE_ID_FK ) and allow extra only this value (-999) to be inserted?

Comment: Maybe the question doesn't clear it. The -999 doesn't exist as an original entry in the parent table RULES. So I got a violation of Foreign Key in my FAVOURITES_RULES table when I am trying to insert this entry

Comment: The short answer is 'no'. You could potentially create a materialised view which combines the real rules with your extra fake one, and use that for the reference; but just adding the extra rule to the real table seems much simpler. Trying to work around integrity constraints makes them a bit pointless though, and doesn't seem like a good idea. If you can't add -999 to the rules table and will only have one extra rule, can you make the `rule_id` nullable and leave it blank instead of having a magic number? It's still not ideal, and eventually someone will want a different extra rule...

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole for your answer

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help.

Step 1: drop fk constraint 
Step 2: insert your violating row
Step 3: again create fk constraint with ENABLE NOVALIDATE

Comment: You don't really want to do that every time you insert a record with that special value; even if you only disable rather than remove the constraint. Partly because it's DDL (which is relatively expensive, and implicitly commits), but also because anything could be inserted by anybody while it's not there.

Comment: Agree with Alex. This should be done only if you don't have a choice but to violate the constraint.